# how to use a graph to understand constraint optimization and Lagrange multipliers

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

[image]

let's say we have a circle on x-y plane and then we tilt the circle around 30 degree and point A is anchor.
[image]

we want to maximize the distance from the point $(x, y, z)$ to the origin $$f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$$ subject to the constraint that the point lie on the circle.
It is obvious that B is the point we want. But according to the optimisation theory,  $\nabla f(x,y,z)$ has to be orthogonal to the tangent plane of B in the circle, but that's impossibile, I know I must have something wrong, but where do I go wrong?

Comment: Do you mean to say that $B$ maximizes the distance to the origin?

Comment: @florence Yes, it is obvious for me that $B$  maximizes the distance to the origin? Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, but you wrote "minimize."

Comment: @florence sorry, I changed it back. And how come $\nabla f(x,y,z)$ has to be orthogonal to the tangent plane of B in the circle? I can't see a way of that

Comment: Are you sure about "the tangent plane of $B$" ? Isn't it true that the gradient is orthogonal to the circle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking in terms of, for example, optimizing a function of two variables on a curve in $\Bbb{R}^2$, or optimizing a function of three variables over a surface in $\Bbb{R}^3$. In these situations, you have a function $f$ which you want to optimize, and a function $g$ so that $g(\mathbf{x})=c$ defines your constraint. Then (roughly) at a local maximum or minimum, we have $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$, where $\lambda$ is a constant, i.e. $\nabla f$ is parallel to $\nabla g$, causing $\nabla f$ to be perpendicular to the curve.

However, this situation is different; we're looking to optimize a function of three variables over a curve in $\Bbb{R}^3$. Provided that $g$ is "nice" enough to work with for these purposes at $c$, any constraint $g(\mathbf{x}) = c$ would actually define a surface (intuitively: $g$ is a function of three variables, setting $g(\mathbf{x})=c$ removes one degree of freedom, leaving a region parametrized by two variables). So, in order to describe the curve in the OP, we wold need two constraints: $g_1(\mathbf{x}) = c_1$ and $g_2(\mathbf{x})=c_2$. In this situation, you find the local extrema by solving the following system of equations: 
$$\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g_1+\mu \nabla g_2$$
Where $\lambda, \mu$ are constants. This equation does not impose any impossible constraints on the direction of $\nabla f$. Geometrically speaking, the curve is the intersection of two surfaces given by $g_1(\mathbf{x}) = c_1$ and $g_2(\mathbf{x})=c_2$ (one for each constraint), and at $B$, $\nabla f$ must merely be in the plane generated by $\nabla g_1 (B)$ and $\nabla g_2(B)$.

Comment: I still don't understand how to get  $g_1(\mathbf{x}) = c_1$ and $g_2(\mathbf{x})=c_2$, how these  $g_1(\mathbf{x})$ and $g_2(\mathbf{x})$ come from the $g(\mathbf{x})$? and

Comment: and let's say $g$ is $x^3+y^2+z$,a function of three variables, setting $g(\mathbf{x,y,z})=c$ , we have $x^3+y^2+z=c$ how come this region is parametrized by two variables rather than three variables?

Comment: $g_1$ and $g_2$ don't "come from" $g$. In order to describe a one-dimensional curve in $\Bbb{R}^3$ you need two constraints to begin with. And the reason that surface is parametrized by two variables is because you can choose $x$ and $y$, but then this automatically determines the value of $z$.

Comment: do you mean the circle is just one-dimensional curve? I think it is still three-dimensional curve?

Comment: It's a one-dimensional curve that exists in three dimensions. Something two-dimensional would be like a surface, something three-dimensional would be like a region that encloses some volume. The important thing here, though, is that you'd need tow constraints to describe it; for a circle on the $x-y$ plane centered at the origin, for instant, you could have $x^2+y^2=1$ and $z=0$.

Comment: Then in your example as $x^2+y^2=1$, and $z=0$, let we tilt the circle 30 degree on point A(-1,0,0), what is the $g_1$ and $g_2$?